# How to set two background color to one element in CSS?

Tags: css

I don't know if it is possible or not .
I'm using bootstrap and i want to assign to the class container-fluid two background color. 50% black and the other 50% red;

```
 <div class="container-fluid bg-footer-text">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-5 left-text">
                asdasdsdasd

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7 right-text">
            <div>
                <img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("/images/pages/services/img_servicii_qa_1.jpg") ?>" alt="Development" />
            </div>
            <div class="content">
        asdsada
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do that? thx

**UPDATE**[image]

I don't care what color will have the container class

Comment: wow seems you want to crate a gradient

Comment: Just search about `linear-gradient`

Comment: i update my post please check it again. I want two background color between the container

Comment: please check the image that i uploaded to be more clear

Comment: just to be sure for the future, why my question is voted down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using a linear gradient background.

[**JSfiddle Backup Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpz3ft01/)

```css
.container-fluid {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black, black 50%, red 50%, red);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```